# onTick method of CountDownTimer in service not executing

Tags: android, service, countdowntimer, android-wake-lock

I have a count down timer in service with partial wake lock which should send SMS in `onTick()` method after a set number of minutes. It works fine on emulator but not on a real device. It executes `onTick()` pretty much when the service start, but I need the SMS to be sent after a delay, which is why I need to set a boolean  `skip` to check for it, but then it doesn't execute `onTick()` again when it should. I'm giving the `onFinish()` an extra 15s just to be sure `onTick()` has enough time but nothing happens.
This is my code, striped of irrelevant clutter for this case:

```
public class SMSService extends Service {

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock = null;
    private boolean skip = true;
    SmsManager mSmsManager;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        mSmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        timer(minutes, true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

            Notification mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
                    .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_text))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_local)
                    .setContentIntent(mPendingIntent)
                    .build();

            startForeground(1, mNotification);
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    void timer(final int minutes, final boolean close) {

        CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(minutes * 60 * 1000 + 15000, minutes * 60 * 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                if (!skip) {
                    mSmsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, sms_body, null, null);
                }
                skip = false;
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (!close) {
                    skip = true;
                    timer(minutes, true);
                }
                else {
                    stopSelf();
                }
            }
        };
        cdt.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: this will need the app to be running for 1 hour till it tick once!!!

Comment: 1000ms = 1sec * 60 = 1 min * minutes... It ticks on every couple of minutes instead of seconds.